# Trimming URLs via Regex, but not to root

Tags: regex, url, dns, trim

I have many URLs, about 100K large.

It looks something like this:

blog.example.com/ilovecats/2011/02/10/the-bling-ring/
blog.example.com/fas24
blog.example.com/morg
blog.example.com/whistlermoar/
blog.example.com/punny/
blog.example.com/punny/2012/10/
blog.example.com/punny/2012/10/01/my-mom-is-alien/
blog.example.com/anniesblog/2012/10/12/i-lost-my-iphone
blog.example.com/anniesblog/2012/10/page/3/
blog.example.com/anniesblog/2012/10/page/4
blog.example.com/anniesblog/2012/10/page/5
blog.example.com/alfva/
blog.example.com/dudewheresmycar/
blog.example.com/mynameisbilly/
blog.example.com/mynameisbilly/page/23/
blog.example.com/anotherflower/category/axel/
blog.example.com/naxramas/
blog.example.com/angeleoooo/
blog.example.com/angeleoooo/2011/01/01/
blog.example.com/angeleoooo/2011/01/01/happynew-years/

I want everything after example.com/username/ to be removed, so the remaining list will look something like this:

blog.example.com/ilovecats/
blog.example.com/fas24
blog.example.com/morg
blog.example.com/whistlermoar/
blog.example.com/punny/
blog.example.com/anniesblog/
blog.example.com/alfva/
blog.example.com/dudewheresmycar/
blog.example.com/mynameisbilly/
blog.example.com/anotherflower/
blog.example.com/naxramas/
blog.example.com/angeleoooo/

I heard that Regex is a way of doing this, so I have been googeling around about this for some hours now and I am about to run out of time.

**Can someone help me?**

(Got Notepad++ installed)

Comment: Try this as regex to match for what you want "^[^/]+/[^/]+".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Presumably you're using the regex search-and-replace function in Notepad++ to try to do this. Is that correct? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
(blog.example.com/\w+\/?).*
```

Put this in Find and be sure to pick 'Regular expression' in the Search Mode.

In the Replace, put:

```
\1
```

And replace all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex to search for.

```
^([.\w]+\/\w+\/?).*
```

Here's the replacement.

```
 \1
```

Let's break it down.  Regular expressions look like you are whistling into a modem unless you break them down carefully.

```
^        only match strings starting at the beginning of a line.
(        begin gathering a bunch of stuff so we can replace it with \1
   [.\w]+   accept a sequence of either dots or characters that appear in words
   \/       accept a / 
   \w+      accept a sequence of characters that can appear in words
   \/?      accept a /, optionally (hence the ?)
)        the end of the parenthesis started above
.*       accept the rest of the string.
```

Notice that I used the + character for the repetitions, because it matches one or more characters.  I could have used *, and did so in the very last item of the regex. That matches zero or more repetitions.

Comment: Sorry for not answering you, you posted your answer exactly the same time as I saw Jerrys answer. Your RegEx also works and thanks for explaining the elements. I edited your RegEx to `^([.\w]+).*`, now it trims to root domain, which I need right now. How do I make it work to trim URLs with prefix http://? My try `^([\w:]+\/\/.\w]+ ).*` but it don't work so good..